# JavaScript iterate through items backwards

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am iterating through some photos using this code:

```js
if (this.lightboxIndex < this.photos.length - 1) {
            this.lightboxIndex++;
          } else {
            this.lightboxIndex = 0;
          }
          this.lightboxSrc = this.photos[this.lightboxIndex].src;
        },
```

How can i iterate backwards through the same photos? Is this along the lines of what I need to do?

```js
if(this.lightboxIndex < this.photos.length - 1){
            this.lightboxIndex--;
          } else {
            this.lightboxIndex = 0;
          }
          this.lightboxSrc = this.photos[this.lightboxIndex].src;
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're iterating down, you need to check for reaching 0, not the highest index, and then go back to the highest index.

```
if (this.lightboxIndex == 0) {
    this.lightboxIndex = this.photos.length - 1;
} else {
    this.lightboxIndex--;
}
```

Your `if` test will always succeed, so it will just keep decrementing the index, going into negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.lightboxIndex > 0) {
    this.lightboxIndex--;
} else {
    this.lightboxIndex = this.photos.length - 1;
}
this.lightboxSrc = this.photos[this.lightboxIndex].src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a decrementing `for` loop?

```
for (this.lightboxIndex = (this.photos.length - 1); this.lightboxIndex >= 0; this.lightboxIndex--) {
  this.lightboxSrc = this.photos[this.lightboxIndex].src;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let think backward will go from `last to first` ,so if it is `first index`,assign to last index else decrease to first index !

forward will go from `first to last` ,so if it is `last index` , assign back to `first index` else increase to last index !

```
this.lightboxIndex = 0;
this.photos = ['a','b','c'];
function forward(){
    if (this.lightboxIndex == this.photos.length -1) {
            this.lightboxIndex = 0;
          } else {
            this.lightboxIndex++;
          }
          this.lightboxSrc = this.photos[this.lightboxIndex];
          console.log(this.lightboxSrc);
      }
function backward () {
    if(this.lightboxIndex == 0) {
    this.lightboxIndex = this.photos.length -1;
    }
    else {
    this.lightboxIndex--;
    }
    this.lightboxSrc = this.photos[this.lightboxIndex];
    console.log(this.lightboxSrc);
}      
      forward();
      forward();
      forward();
      backward();
      backward();
      backward();
```